# NavMeshAgent not working at Y positions < 0

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a level, the floors of which are mostly at zero height but some sections that slope down to go below zero. I have a simple script attached to an object to randomly set a destination for the NavMeshAgent. When moving on the zero Y position floors it works fine, but if I place the object in a lower part of the level it doesn't and NavMeshAgent.SetDestination always returns false.

Here's a doodle of the level:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
void Start () {
    nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    StartCoroutine(Move());
}

IEnumerator Move()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Vector3 randomPoint = transform.position + new Vector3(Random.Range(0, roamRadius),
            transform.position.y, Random.Range(0, roamRadius));

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, randomPoint, Color.green, 0.5f);

        Debug.Log(nav.SetDestination(randomPoint));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(changeDirectionSpeed + Random.Range(0, changeDirectionSpeedRandom));
    }

}
```

I've tried checking for the nearest position to my random vector with NavMesh.SamplePosition; a position is always found on the upper level but never on the lower level.

I've used various settings to bake the NavMesh right down to agent radius of 0.1 with no effect. I am certain there is NavMesh in place in the lower level and the agent is placed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Because your y position will be in the air if you use transform.position.y.

Suggest that you do a raycast from say transform.position.y + 10f and the hitpoint will be your new destination point